# Toggle autofocus between two Textfields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, autofocus

In my `react app` I have 10 `material-UI textfields`. The first 8 textfields are inside an expansion panel and the last two textfields are inside another expansion panel. What I need is to **toggle** autofocus between the last two, so that when user enters data in the first one, after he hits 'enter', the next textfield will be autofocused and vice versa, when data is entered on the second textfield, the first one will be autofocused.

This is one of the textfields:

```
                <TextField
                  autofocus={this.state.depotFocused}
                  id="standard-name"
                  value={this.state.depot}
                  defaultValue={this.state.depot}
                  onChange={ev => this.setState({ depot: ev.target.value })}
                  onKeyPress={ev => {
                        if (ev.key === "Enter") {
                          this.handleDepotChange();
                          ev.preventDefault();
                        }
                      }}
                  margin="normal"
                />
```

My first implementation was changing state of autofocus on *Key Press*. So, when user hits 'enter' and leaves the first textfield, this.state.depotFocused becomes false and this.state.folderFocused becomes true (that is the next textfield). The problem is, as others have mentioned, that autofocus is not working at all like this.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The property autofocus only focuses the TextField when it's mounted, so that shouldn't be the thing you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created an example on how to manually switch focus of the TextFields:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

class TextFields extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
        <TextField
          autoFocus
          inputRef={node => {
            this.firstField = node;
          }}
          onKeyPress={ev => {
            if (ev.key === "Enter") {
              ev.preventDefault();
              this.secondField.focus();
            }
          }}
        />
        <TextField
          inputRef={node => {
            this.secondField = node;
          }}
          onKeyPress={ev => {
            if (ev.key === "Enter") {
              ev.preventDefault();
              this.firstField.focus();
            }
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<TextFields />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

[image: Edit TextField focus change]